# Wolfram Kernel and Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: python, wolfram-client, amazon-web-services

I've got a python project that uses the wolframclient library that I want to deploy onto AWS elastic beanstalk.

I've tried installing Wolfram Engine through ssh, but wolframclient is having issues using the kernel even though the correct file path is given.

(WolframKernelException: Failed to communicate with kernel:/usr/local/Wolfram/WolframEngine/12.3/Executables/wolfram)

Any ideas on what the best way to go about this is?

Thanks

edit:
Tried using  default Wolfram engine install location, no luck

Also, wolfram engine is activated, I can run ./wolfram and execute WL code in the command line/

Comment: Some questions: 1) How are you installing the Wolfram Engine? `/Wolfram/Executables/WolframKernel` is not to my knowledge a standard installation path for the WolframKernel executable, so I'm wondering if `wolframclient` is looking in the wrong place. 2) Have you made sure to [activate](https://support.wolfram.com/46072) the Wolfram Engine before trying to run your application?

Comment: Also - Elastic Beanstalk supports Docker-based applications; have you considered running your application in a container using the [Wolfram Engine Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/wolframresearch/wolframengine)?